# How to put an EditText in a DialogBox?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, dialog

I have this code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etC" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@string/amount_credits"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

and

```
    AlertDialog.Builder creditsBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    edC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC); 
    creditsBox.setView(edC); //THIS LINE MAKES THE APP CRASH
    creditsBox.setMessage("Enter amount of credits")
      .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    AlertDialog creditsBoxC = creditsBox.create(); 
    creditsBoxC.show();
```

Now I don't understand where is the problem. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could not set **EditText** like that.

Try this:

- Create new layout (which contains EditText)
- Inflate that layout
- Set that layout for AlertDialog

Here is the `res/layout/prompts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_nm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your **Activity**

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_nm);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                      });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are getting an error message somewhere along the lines of "View already has a parent"
The problem is, that you are trying to reuse the same EditText object each time you build your alert. 
So either get a new EditText object by creating it dynamically with `edc = new EditText();`
or use the  `inflate()` method rather than `findViewById()`, since inflating it will give you a new Instance everytime.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
EditText etC;

LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(yourActivity.this);
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);          
etC= (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.etC);

new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this)
.setTitle("xx")
.setIcon(R.drawable.logo3)
.setView(textEntryView)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(classname.this);    
View dialogView =li.inflate(R.layout.common_dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder dialogwindow = new AlertDialog.Builder(classname.this);
                                dialogwindow.setView(dialogView);_addEditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogtext);
_dialogTextView=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview);
```

here is xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Text : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```